# Can I prove this inequality algebraically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

With $x+y\ge z$ $(x,y,z\ge0)$, prove that: $$\frac{x}{1+x}+\frac{y}{1+y}\ge\frac{z}{1+z}$$

I'm aware that using analytic view this is easy since $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is concave in $[0,\infty)$. However I want to prove it using merely algebraic techniques. Is that possible?

Comment: Write $\frac{w}{1+w}=1-\frac{1}{1+w}$ for $w=x,y,z$ and then you need to show $\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{1+y}\leq 1 + \frac{1}{z+1}$. Proving this is fairly direct algebraically.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks for your advice but IMHO that makes it even more difficult to prove.

Comment: What have you tried either this way or your own?  What is the most obvious thing you can do for an "algebraic" proof?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309198/if-dx-y-is-a-metric-then-fracdx-y1-dx-y-is-also-a-metric

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The conditions certainly give  $xyz + 2xy + x + y \ge z$

which is a simplification of  $x(1 + y)(1 + z) + (1 + x)y(1 + z)  \ge  (1 + x)(1 + y)z$.

Now just divide all that by  $(1 + x)(1 + y)(1 + z)$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Probably 'cause he didn't use $\LaTeX$.

Comment: This looks fine to me. So I ask, too: why the downvotes?

Comment: @Voldemort: I certainly hope not. That is no way to greet a newcomer. Instead of downvoting, or at least in addition to downvoting, suggest the use of $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @robjohn: I agree. That's why I gave him upvote and a suggestion.

Comment: Ken, Welcome. You might want to look at [this helpful introduction to $\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

How about this? As Thomas Andrews observed, write $\frac{w}{1+w}=1−\frac{1}{1+w}$ for $w=x,y,z$ and then you need to show $\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1+y} \le 1 + \frac{1}{z+1}$.

Now, $$1 + \frac{1}{z+1} \ge 1 + \frac{1}{x+y+1} = \frac{x+y+2}{x+y+1} \ge \frac{(x+1)+(y+1)}{1+x+y+xy} = \frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1+y}$$ and we're done. Equality holds when one of $x,y$ is $0$, and $z=x+y$.

Comment: (so equality holds when one of $x$ or $y$ is zero and the other is equal to $z$)

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}=1-\frac1{x+1}$ is increasing we can consider the case $a,b< c$ then

$$\frac{c}{c+1}< \frac{a+b}{c+1}=\frac{a}{c+1}+\frac{b}{c+1}<\frac{a}{a+1}+\frac{b}{b+1}$$