# About a metric over $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I need some help with this exercise:

let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We consider:

$K_m=\lbrace{x\in\Omega, d(x,\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega)\geq\frac{1}{m},|x|\leq m}\rbrace$

If $\Phi\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$, we define:

$q_m(\Phi)=sup\lbrace{|D^{\alpha}\Phi(x)|, |\alpha|\leq m, x\in K_m}\rbrace$ (where $\alpha$ is a multiindex)

Let $d(\Phi,\Psi)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^m}\frac{q_m(\Phi-\Psi)}{1+q_m(\Phi-\Psi)}$

I have to prove that this defines a metric over $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: where are you stuck? surely some parts of this proof are straight forward!

Comment: @martini Duh. How did I overlook that?

Comment: I'm stuck in the triangle inequality. As you say, Prahlad, the other conditions are easy.

Comment: First prove it for each $q_m$, then see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309198/metric-spaces-analysis. Then take the infinite sum.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: (most of these I expect you've seen)

1. Let $(X,d)$ be a (pseudo)metric space. Show that $\delta(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ defines a bounded (pseudo)metric on $X$.
2. Let $(d_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a family of pseudometrics on $X$ such that for all $x,y\in X$ the sequence $(d_n(x,y))_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded. Show that $\eta(x,y) = \sum_{n\geq 1}2^{-n}d_n(x,y)$ defines a pseudometric on $X$, and that if the family is separating then $\eta$ is a metric.
3. It might be worthwhile to represent
   $$q_m(\Phi) = \max\left\lbrace \sup\{|D^\alpha\Phi(x)|:x\in K_m\} : |\alpha|\leq m\right\rbrace$$

Comment: How can i prove that those $q_m$ are metrics?

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman, first take a specific $|\alpha|\leq m$, and show that $q_m^\alpha(\Phi):=\sup\{|D^\alpha\Phi(x)|:x\in K_m\}$ is a pseudonorm on $C^\infty(\Omega)$. Then handle $q_m$. Finally, don't forget to show that the $q_m$'s are separating.