# Does this metric on the space of real sequences have a name?

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

During my research, someone mentioned the following metric on the space of real sequences:
$$d(x,y)=\sum_i 2^{-i}\frac{|x_i-y_i|}{1+|x_i-y_i|}$$
I was wondering whether this metric had a name or there was a source mentioning this metric?

The commenter also seemed to imply that with this metric, you can 'extend' the lebesgue measure on binary sequences to this space to a probability measure on the space of real sequences. However I don't see how these ideas are linked, as I don't even see a 'natural' probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ associated with this metric (if that even makes sense).

Comment: It may be called the product metric because (with the usual topology on $\Bbb R$) it generates the (Tychonoff) product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ which is sometimes called the topology of pointwise convergence: Consider  real sequences as functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R.$ Then  $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(f_n,f)=0$ iff $\forall k\in\Bbb N\,(\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(k)=f(k)\,).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a transformation of the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$. If $$d(x,y)$$ is a metric, then $$ \dfrac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)}$$ is also a metric. Here $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

The scaling by powers of 2 ensures absolute convergence. See, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948450/proving-that-the-sequence-space-is-a-metric-space-in-mathbbr) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309198/if-dx-y-is-a-metric-then-fracdx-y1-dx-y-is-also-a-metric)