# Question about open set of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

if $(S,d)$ is a metric space then $\mu(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ is also a metric space on $S$ and a set $A$ is open in $(S,d)$ iff it is open in $(S,\mu)$.
I understand the first part that $(S,\mu)$ is also metric space however I am not getting any idea about the rest. can someone give some hints, that would be a great help.

Comment: Consider for example $(\mathbf{R}^{2},d)$ with $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ it is a metric space. The proposition says a set $A\subseteq \mathbf{R}^{2}$ is open in $(\mathbf{R}^{2},d)$ iff is open in $(\mathbf{R}^{2},\mu)$. You can study that particular case and then to think in the general case $(S,d)$ metric space.

Comment: can you give some hint to prove it in general.

Comment: The key is to study the definition of open set. If $A\subset S$ is a open subset so by definition what can you say?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $d(x,y)$ is a metric, then $\frac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)}$ is also a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309198/if-dx-y-is-a-metric-then-fracdx-y1-dx-y-is-also-a-metric)

Answer (score 2):

In a metric space, the best way to prove that a topology $\mathcal{T}_d$ is coarser that the topology $\mathcal{T}_\mu$ is to use the bases consisting of open balls i.e. to prove that for every $x\in X$ and every $r>$ there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that
$$B_\epsilon^\mu (x) \subseteq B_r^d (x)$$
in other words every metric open ball in the sense of the metric $d$ centered at $x$ contains another metric open ball in the sense of $\mu$ contained in it.
This is done by realizing
$$\mu(x,y)$$
$$=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$$
$$\le \frac{d(x,y)}{1}$$
$$\le d(x,y)$$
and, hence,
$$y\in B_r^{d} (x)$$
$$\Rightarrow d(x,y)<r$$
$$\Rightarrow \mu(x,y)<r \text{ since } \mu(x,y)\le d(x,y)$$
$$\Rightarrow y\in B_r^{\mu} (x)$$
which means that for every $x\in X$ and for every $r>0$,
$$B_r^{\mu} (x)\subseteq B_r^{d} (x)$$
so every open set in $\mathcal{T}_{d}$ is also open in $\mathcal{T}_{\mu}$

Answer (score 1):

We'll show that a set $A$ is closed in $(S,d)$ iff $A$ is closed in $(S,\mu)$.

$\implies:$

Let $A$ be closed in $(S,d)$. Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $A$ that converges to some $x \in S$ in the metric $\mu$. That is, $\mu(x_n,x) \to 0$. To show that $x \in A$, the strategy is to show that $d(x_n,x) \to 0$.
But we must have that since:
$$\mu(x_n,x) = \frac{d(x_n,x)}{1+d(x_n,x)}$$
it must be the case that:
$$\mu(x_n,x)(1+d(x_n,x)) = d(x_n,x)$$
$$d(x_n,x) = \frac{\mu(x_n,x)}{1-\mu(x_n,x)}$$
Since $\mu(x_n,x) \to 0$, it follows that $d(x_n,x) \to 0$. Since $A$ is closed in $(S,d)$, this means that $x \in A$.

$\impliedby:$

Now, let $A$ be closed in $(S,\mu)$. We want to show that it is closed in $(S,d)$. Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $A$ that converges to some $x \in S$ in the metric $(S,d)$. That is, $d(x_n,x) \to 0$. I'll leave it to you to show that $\mu(x_n,x) \to 0$. But this will imply that $x \in A$ and you're done. $\Box$

All of this is a consequence of the fact that a subset $A \subseteq X$ of a metric space $(X,d)$ is closed iff every convergent sequence in $A$ converges inside of $A$.